# EclipseLink eager weaving

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I want to use EclipseLink ChangeTrackingType set to ATTRIBUTE.
The problem it doesn't work with ElementCollection where fetch is set to FetchType.EAGER.
In EclipseLink documentation bellow they mention "eager weaving" which solves this but I couldn't find anywhere on the net and documentation on how to do such thing.

[EclipseLink ChangeTrackingType documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_changetracking.htm)

How do I enable "eager weaving"?

Answer (score 1):

Need to add eclipselink.weaving.eager="true" in the persistent unit properties.